# How do I disable IPython when opening a Django shell

Tags: django, ipython

If it is a multi-user environment and uninstall IPython is not an option, how would you go about launching a Django shell without IPython.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Django 1.10 the `--plain` flag is deprecated, instead you should use `-i` flag to choose from available interactive shells {ipython,bpython,python}

```
./manage.py shell -i python
```

Answer (score 5):

[Passing `--plain`](https://github.com/django/django/commit/5e6d6fafae) will tell Django to not look for IPython.

Answer (score 0):

you can `uninstall ipython` from the project virtualenv, that all you need

Comment: The question was just two lines long and contained “uninstall IPython is not an option”.